# DQN not learning anything - Reinforcement Learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to train a DQN to play the [8puzzle game](https://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/algs4/assignments/8puzzle/specification.php).

**I have implemented a batched gameboards, so I am not using `ReplayMemory`.**

Here's training process:

```py
finished_counts = torch.tensor(0, device=device)
pbar = tqdm(range(int(1e4)))
for e in pbar:
    q_values = net(board) # board: Tensor with shape [10000, 3, 3]
    
    # choose action randomly or by q_values
    if np.random.rand() < 0.5:
        actions = torch.randint(0, 4, (board.size(0),)).to(device)
    else:
        actions = torch.argmax(q_values, dim=1)

    # reward: -100 for hit the wall, 10 for win, 0 for else
    reward, next_board = move(board, actions)

    next_q = net(next_board).detach()
    next_q[reward == 10] = 0 # ignore next_q if already win

    desired_q = q_values.clone().detach()
    distance = manhattan(next_board)
    desired_q[:, actions] = (reward - distance) + next_q[:, actions] * q_decay # q_decay = 0.9

    # set metrics
    pbar.set_postfix({
        'avg distance': f'{torch.mean(distance):.2f}',
        'finished': str(finished_counts.cpu().item()),
    })

    # compute loss and backwards
    # HuberLoss for criterion
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = criterion(q_values, desired_q)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step() # Adam(lr=1e-4)

    board = next_board

    finished = distance == 0
    board = board[~finished]
    finished_counts += finished.sum()
```

What I obeserved is, the `avg distance` is remaing around `12.67`, and `finished_counts` increasing in linear rate, which may attributed to random action.

My question is:

1. Is it ok to not use ReplayMemory?
2. Am I calculate the `q_values` and `desired_q` correct?
3. Why is the network not learning anything?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out a little with many experiments, here's some key rules needs to obey during building the model and training:

1. Keep positive samples and nagetive samples balanced.
   You have to let the Agent win, then it can learn a path leads to win. You can set to low difficulty initally, or guide it(by setting milestones of the game, and if it reaches the goal, give it a big reward). Sometimes you have to decrease the `batch size` to include more positive samples within a batch.
2. Do not `torch.log(MSE(y_hat, y))`, I don't know why.
3. Limit the Agent's max step, the random action will distrub Agent, pushing the game difficulty to higher, you don't want it to play a high difficulty game initially.
4. My code is wrong:

   ```py
   next_q = net(next_board).detach()
   next_q = next_q.max(1)[0] # notice: use next_q's max value
   next_q[reward == GAME_WIN_REWARD] = 0 # ignore next_q if already win

   q_values = q_values.gather(1, actions.unsqueeze(1)).squeeze(1)
   distance = manhattan(next_board)
   desired_q = (reward - distance ** 2) + next_q * q_decay # I reinforce the effect of the distance
   ```

Here's how I train:
learning rate: `0.00005` (constant)
`MAX_STEP: 10 * DIFFICULTY`
`BATCH_SIZE = 100`

| `DIFFICULTY` | `EXPLORE RATE` | `EPISODE` | mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `5` | `0.8` | `2e4` | initally low difficulty |
| `5` | `0.7` | `1e4` |  |
| `5` | `0.6` | `1e4` |  |
| `5` | `0.5` | `1e4` |  |
| `5` | `0.4` | `1e4` |  |
| `5` | `0.2` | `1e4` |  |
| `5` | `0` | `1e4` | reinforce memory |
| `6` | `0.3` | `1e4` |  |
| `6` | `0.1` | `1e4` |  |
| `6` | `0` | `1e4` | reinforce memory |
| `6` | `0.1` | `4e4` | I found the Agent has bad performace in difficulty of 6 |
| `6` | `0` | `1e4` |  |
| `7` | `0.3` | `1e4` |  |
| `7` | `0.1` | `1e4` |  |
| `7` | `0` | `1e4` |  |